# How to get image file metadata (exif) with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

in windows explorer, you can choose to show the dimensions of files (images), is there a way to get that metadata with python without PIL, maybe os

Comment: Python's standard library has **no** module to work with images or image's metadata (exif).

Comment: maybe I should clarify: in Windows, if I open a folder, there is a list of the files.  In the menu bar of Windows Explorer, I check select dimensions and then the dimensions of each image should in a column in the Explorer window.  It seems Windows already know the pixel dimension...is there a way of getting that information with Python

Answer (score 0):

You should see this Python Module:

https://pypi.org/project/ExifRead/

Comment: This seems like a good package for tiff and jpeg image files.